# Parallax scrolling horizontal

Tags: javascript

I dont know where to begin. The demo page is here: http://www.perandersen.no/sandbox/parallax/

I use jQuery and the plugin scrollTo. Then I attach a function to the window.onscroll. Sorry it's a bit messy, but please help me optimize it. I am new to JavaScript:

```
function scroll()
{
 var xPos = window.pageXOffset;


 var element = $("#wrapper");
 var newXPos = Math.abs(xPos /1.1);
 element.css( "left", newXPos );

 element = $("#snowboarder");
 var newXPos = Math.abs(xPos /1.5) + snowboarderPos.left;
 element.css( "left", newXPos );

 element = $("#elevator");
 var newXPos = Math.abs(xPos /1.9) + 2800;
 element.css( "left", newXPos );

  var element = $("#ballong");
 var newXPos = Math.abs(xPos /1.2) + balloonPos.left;
 element.css( "left", newXPos );

// $("#xpos").text(window.pageXOffset);
}
```

I set the snowboarderPos as a global in the beginning of the script tag som taht it is set before anything happends. On the Elevator object I have hard coded it in this version.

EDIT: Works best in Chrome with a faster processor... so it needs to be optimized.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: @JeffreySweeney did you look at the link?

Comment: lagging on the browser in FF mainly. And also on slower computers.

Comment: @locrizak Yes. I wasn't sure if Per-Øivin Andersen was looking for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having:

```
element.css( "left", newXPos );
```

have you tried:

```
element.stop().animate( {left:newXPos}, 200 );
```

Comment: element.stop().animate( {left:newXPos}, 0); creates the desired effect, but not with 200. But still very laggy in FF.

Comment: Agreed; instead of animating those elements yourself, use the `animate()` functions of jQuery (they are already optimized). There is also a stop function to clear all animations if you need to "reset" things for the next "move" in the game.

Comment: @Aaron how is that different than what I said. The 200 was just an example try 20-50

Comment: sorry it's still laggy on 20-50 in FF only.

Comment: or at least in FF. I don't know about the different OSes and Safari. IE is OK but scrolls really slow on manual scroll...

Comment: try getting rid of Math.abs and what does `snowboarderPos` equal to?

Comment: thanks for pointing out that math.abs was unecessary, but it does not affect the FF lag as far as I can see. I have removed them though.

Comment: Try using `$(window).scrollLeft()` There is no lag it has to do with how you are positioning your elements

Comment: @locrizak Thanks for all your help btw. But I don't understand this one. scrollLeft() gets the scrollbar position of the element. How could I use that in this context?

Comment: It is the same as `var xPos = window.pageXOffset`

Comment: I tried var xPos = $(window).scrollLeft(); but still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to make it seem more responsive is to add a -moz-transition-duration css property to the elements being scrolled. If there are only a few elements, setting the duration to 0.33s or something similar could make it seem quicker.

Comment: this one seems to make everything "hang behind" then it catches up to the scroll later. But thank you for the input. PS. it might be that this could help if I expand the solution a bit, so I will keep this trick in mind.